# Display Account Insights in a custom app?

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components

Account and contact detail pages can include a component that displays account/contact insights (news). How can I display news inside a custom component app either in a visualforce page or a lightning app?

Comment: What have you tried so far in order to do this Artur? Have you tried writing a custom Lightning component? If so, please post your code.

Comment: I cannot find any API access to this feature, hence there is no code to share.